# How to handle nested conditionals

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a function where I would like to return True if a number of conditions are met. For example, consider this function which compares two strings:

```
test st1 st2
    | st1 == st2
        | "foo" `isInfixOf` st1 = True
        | "baz" `isInfixOf` st2 = True
        | otherwise = False
    | otherwise = False
```

Obviously, this function is incorrect. However, I'm looking for a way to test several conditions and I wanted to know:

A) what is the clearest way to do this?
B) is there an approach similar to what i have generated that uses guards?

For clarity, in my simple example above, the output of `test` should be the following:

```
test "foobuz" "foobuz" = True
test "foobutter" "foobuz" = False
test "buz" "buz" = False
```

N.B. Chaining conditions together might be an option, but it gets very unreadable after only two or three tests:

```
test st1 st2 = st1 == st2 && "foo" `isInfixOf` s1 || "baz" `isInfixOf` s2
```

I was thinking there might be a way to use the Endo Monoid to test a chain of several conditionals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sebastian's suggestion of local helpers is a good one. However, the particular example you've given essentially boils down to `if CONDITION then True else False`, which can be replaced with `CONDITION`. So you could simply write:

```
main = print (fac 5)
test st1 st2 = st1 == st2 && ("foo" `isInfixOf` st1' || "baz" `isInfixOf` st2)
```

Another way to write this is:

```
main = print (fac 5)
test st1 st2
    | st1 == st2 && "foo" `isInfixOf` st1 = True
    | st1 == st2 && "baz" `isInfixOf` st2 = True
    | otherwise                           = False
```

Comment: In your second variant, Have you checked that `st1 == st2` is not checked twice? I.e, does the compiler optimize that away?

Answer (score 4):

I would use local helpers.

```
test st1 st2
    | st1 == st2 = test_after_eq st1 st2
    | otherwise = False
  where test_after_eq st1' st2'
            | "foo" `isInfixOf` st1' = True
            | "baz" `isInfixOf` st2' = True
            | otherwise = False
```

I think that should work.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine a case expression and patterns guards:

```
test st1 st2 = case st1 == st2 of
    True | "foo" `isInfixOf` st1 -> ...
         | "baz" `isInfixOf` st2 -> ...
         |  otherwise            -> ...
    False -> ...
```

Comment: Does this work ? It's not typechecking for me. Throws this error: `    parse error on input `='` I tried this code: http://lpaste.net/98226

Comment: Should have used `->` instead of `=`, as this is a case expression. sorry.

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can get to the way it looks in your original code is with the `MultiWayIf` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}

test st1 st2
   | st1 == st2  = ( if
      | "foo" `isInfixOf` st1 -> True
      | "baz" `isInfixOf` st2 -> True
      | otherwise             -> False )
   | otherwise                =  False
```

---

Of course, for this particular example it can be done better with other means – the other answers already gave a couple of suggestions, here's one more (since you've tested `st1==st2` anyway)

```
test st1 st2 = st1==st2 && any (`isInfixOf`st1) ["foo", "baz"]
```

Answer (score 4):

While `case` is usually overkill for matching on booleans, it does give you a new context for guards.

```
test st1 st2 = case (st1 == st2) of
  True  | "foo" `isInfixOf` st1 -> True
        | "baz" `isInfixOf` st2 -> True
        | otherwise             -> False
  False                         -> False
```

You can also use pairing to form more exotic `case`-based nested `if`s.

```
foo a b c = case (p1 a b, p2 b c, p3 a c) of
  (True,  _    , _   ) -> val1
  (False, False, True) -> val2
  (False, True , _   ) -> val3
```

Comment: It seems you have the same syntax error than my answer, to which your answer is surprisingly similar. Did you copy from me?

Comment: I didn't actually, but I did never test my code. I make that syntax error all the time though.

Comment: I like the idea of using `case` (2nd fragment) because of automatic memoization of test expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Using `and` and `or`:

```
test st1 st2 = and [ st1 == st2
                   , or ["foo" `isInfixOf` st1
                        ,"baz" `isInfixOf` st2] ]
```

Using the `All` and `Any` monoids:

```
test' st1 st2 = getAll . foldMap All $
    [ st1 == st2
    , getAny . foldMap Any $ ["foo" `isInfixOf` st1
                             ,"baz" `isInfixOf` st2]]
```

The `ala` function from `Control.Lens.Wrapped` can sometimes simplify the wrapping/unwrapping of newtypes, but here it doesn't save us much:

```
test'' st1 st2 = ala All foldMap 
    [st1 == st2
    ,ala Any foldMap  ["foo" `isInfixOf` st1
                      ,"baz" `isInfixOf` st2 ]]
```